# How can I make a Java Application fullscreen in Linux?

Tags: java, linux

I built a Java app using Eclipse Oxygen as "Runnable JAR file". I am using the latest Java developer kit and the latest Java runtime. I downloaded the jar file to my Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Debian Stretch with Raspberry Pi Desktop. When I launched my application (via the terminal `java -jar application.jar` ), it ran smoothly. However, I included code that would make the window full screen. The code worked on my Windows 10 host machine. How do I make a JFrame full screen on Linux?

I've tried all the possible solutions I can think of. Some of which include...

```java
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

However, that did not work.

I don't seem to be getting any error messages. Any clue to what's going on? I was expecting that it would work.

Comment: Try moving the `setExtendedState` after `setVisible`

Answer (score 0):

from what i could understand shells like gnome or kde don't detect the panel as "part of the screen" so you can't cover it